# Forwarding HTTP requests in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

This is the scenario I'm trying to achieve in Play 2.5.x for Scala (all the requests and responses are Json):

1. Browser sends HTTP Request to URL1.
2. URL1 enriches the Json it receives with some data, and forwards the entire request to URL2.
3. URL2 responds to browser.

In the last point, I'm not sure if URL2 can send it back to the browser or has to do it through URL1 (I believe it's the latter).

This is the request in URL1 (URL2 is a simple request/response):

```
  val request: WSRequest = ws.url("/url2")
  val request2: WSRequest = request.withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
  val data = Json.obj(
        "aaa" -> some_data1,
        "bbb" -> some_data2
   )
   val futureResponse: Future[JsValue] = request2.post(data).map {
            response => response.json
   }
```

When I send the future I get this exception:

```
Execution exception[[NullPointerException: scheme]]
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the function name - it's `ws.url`, not `ws.uri`.  You need to specify a complete path.  You can use `ws.url("http://localhost:9000/url2")`, with customised elements if necessary such as the scheme and the port based on your configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes you suggested and the exception went away. However, URL2 is not getting the request. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: Update the question with your routes file, logs, etc.  Also, try increasing the number of threads available in development mode.  Even better, create a new question to make it easier for people to navigate to these separate issues.

Comment: This is the problem: since it's a new URL I don't have the cookies I had in the original session, so the application fails. Bypassing that it works.

Comment: Try forming the URL by getting the host and port from the incoming request.

Comment: Thanks. I see in the incoming request headers `Referer,http://localhost:9000/)` and I'm already formatting the URL as `http://localhost:9000/url2`

Comment: Can you please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304713/forwarding-in-play-for-scala-returns-empty-response)? thanks.