# Forwarding in Play for Scala returns empty response

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

The HTTP forward below (`futureResponse` function) returns an empty response to the browser. Any ideas what is wrong and/or where should I look at?

```
  val request: WSRequest = ws.url("http://somehost/url2")
  val request2: WSRequest = request.withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
  val data = Json.obj(
        "aaa" -> some_data1,
        "bbb" -> some_data2
   )
   val futureResponse: Future[JsValue] = request2.post(data).map {
     response => 
         val json= Json.obj(
             "ccc" -> "111",
             "ddd" -> "222"
            )
         json
   }

   Ok(json)
```

When I get the message in the browser, the data in the response is empty:

[image]

Comment: It mainly depends on what you do with whatever you return from this.

Comment: All I need is to return to the browser the Json received in the Future, always in Json format.

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: Can you update with the action code?  Right now, this shows you returning a Future containing JSON, but not what you're doing with it.

Comment: I added `OK(json)` however it still returns empty data to the browser, does `OK(json)` wait until the Future populates the `json` variable?

Comment: Does this compile? The `json` variable, in my opinion, should not be accessible outside of the `request2.post(data).map` body.

Comment: No, does not compile, I just added the variable to show the `Ok` function

Comment: @bennie-krijger 's answer should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the action asynchronous and reply a Future[Result], like:

```
def someAction = Action.async { implicit request =>
  val request: WSRequest = ws.url("http://somehost/url2")
  val request2: WSRequest = request.withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
  val data = Json.obj(
    "aaa" -> some_data1,
    "bbb" -> some_data2
  )
  val futureResponse: Future[JsValue] = request2.post(data).map { response => 
     val json= Json.obj(
         "ccc" -> "111",
         "ddd" -> "222"
     )

     Ok(json)
  }

  futureResponse
}
```